# Jenkins config.xml files vanished

Tags: jenkins

I've just noticed that the Jenkins's jobs that have been present for years have disappeared from our CI system.

On closer inspection it seems the config.xml files have gone missing for every job.

The job directories themselves and all their contents (such as all the build history etc. etc.) are all still present, only the config.xml files have vanished.

If somebody had accidentally deleted the jobs then the entire directories would no longer be present, but as its only the config.xml files that have gone missing, and as its the config.xml files that have gone missing for every job it seems very strange.

Has anybody encountered anything this before?

(Jenkins 1.492 on OS X)

Comment: Yes, I did and it ended up to be human error. There was some weird combination of runaway job and thoughtless scripting that destroyed these files. Unfortunately, one doesn't notice till the next restart of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone might have clicked on it

Manage jenkins >Manage old data

www.xxxxx.jenkins.com/administrativeMonitor/OldData/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I just went through a similar issue and the "Manage Old Data" task was what got us.

We started working the issue when I had a user who could not create a new job from an existing job.  The error ID lead me to find out that it could not copy because the `config.xml` file was missing.  Then I looked through all the build directories and more to find how deep the issue really was.

It wiped out all of my build config.xml `(/var/lib/jenkins/JOB_NAME/config.xml)` files as well as all my build node directories `(/var/lib/jenkins/nodes)`. It looked like it may have also taken out my users directories `(/var/lib/jenkins/users)`. Luckily we backup the entire Jenkins directory so I wasn't completely panicked.

To resolve I went into every job and saved it which recreated the `config.xml` file. I also went through every node and saved them which created their directory and `config.xml` file.

If we had restarted Jenkins while all the **.xml** files were missing I would have had to copy them all from our backup system.

We are running Jenkins 2.263.  Google search was not useful except for this one little post that happens to mention "Manage Old Data".  I recall going through "Manage Old Data" several weeks ago while trouble shooting another issue.

Would love to hear more about the intent of this 'feature' that nearly obliterated my Jenkins instance. The [Jenkins notes for this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/) are somewhat lacking of info.

@tizki-ko @tidhar-klein-orbach I read your article on "[5 Simple tips for boosting your Jenkins performance](https://blog.taboola.com/5-simple-tips-boosting-jenkins-performance/)" and hope you can add your thoughts.